# LuaInterface: How to access multi dimensional lua table?

Tags: c#, lua, lua-table, luainterface

I am new to LuaInterface and have a very simple question: How can I access data from a multi dimensional lua table from c#? I managed to read strings and integer values but was not lucky with tables. My goal is to display the content of a multidimensional lua table in a (virtual) GridView.

Sorry, I think this is a really simple question but I was unable to find neither a good documentation nor a compileable example project. You can also point me to the documentation if you think I should RTFM first before asking here - but I could not find any.

thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

LuaInterface wrapped the Table type to LuaTable.
So, if you define a multi dimensional table in Lua

```
t = {}
t[1] = {}
t[1][1] = 888
ShowTable(t)     -- assume ShowTable is a C# function
```

You can use the code below to access lua table in C#

```
public void ShowTable(LuaTable t)
{
    LuaTable t1 = t[1];
    Console.WriteLine(t1[1]);   // should display 888
    t.Dispose();                  // Don't forget to Dispose the table sent from Lua to C#, or memory leak happens!
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work now! Thanks also for the hint to dispose it afterwards.